# Getting the absolute size of iframe contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an application in which I load an external website into an Iframe so people can QA it I need to find a way of getting the absolute size of the contents inside of the iframe so all the contents that are hidden because you havent scrolled down to that at the moment I can only seem to get the size of iframe just on the screen i.e. i have an iframe size of 800x600 and i can only get this value for some reason, but the website may be 800x1200 i need to be able to get that full size.

Currently i have this code

```
        aWidth = document.getElementById('FrameStyle').scrollWidth - 17;
        aHeight = document.getElementById('FrameStyle').scrollHeight + 500;
```

This is getting me the height but i have to manually add on pixels to the end which is not how i want and also the website may be longer than just 500 more pixels. So how can I go about getting the complete size of the iframes inner contents.

Comment: try this:

`var HEIGHT=iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";`

Comment: Hmm still had no affect.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use `Dot_NET Junior's` suggestion if you run the code once the `iframe` contents have loaded, e.g.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');
iframe.onload = function () {
    var width = iframe.contentDocument.body.scrollWidth;
    var height = iframe.contentDocument.body.scrollHeight;
};
```

Comment: Security error when i used it, cross domain security